# Get history/log of a (potentially removed) file in Git

Tags: git

How can I view history on a particular file (which may have been deleted already in the current trunk)?

Also, what diff tool do you suggest for mac?

Comment: I suggest only asking one question per post.  Since your title refers to the first part of your question, I suggest moving the bit about the diff tool on a mac into a separate post/question.

Answer (score 11):

Do this to view the history for a file, even if it has been deleted from the current HEAD:

```
git log -- <filename>
```

So if you deleted `xyz.py` a few revisions ago but would like to view its history, then you would do:

```
git log -- xyz.py
```

Comment: If the file has been renamed in the past, you may want to use `git log --follow -- <path>`

Answer (score 0):

> Also, what diff tool do you suggest for mac?

The Mac dev tools come with FileMerge, which is a decent diff tool. There's a command-line interface to it called `opendiff` (also ships with the dev tools).